# counting number of multiplication operations performed in algorithms

Tags: summation, algorithms, computer-science

as the title says I need to find the number of multiplication operations performed in the following two algorithms. The problem is we weren't given any type of help and im not really sure even how to start going about this. Any help in how to find the number of multiplication operations being used in these two algorithms would be much appreciated. thanks

1. $$U'ab = \sum_{i}^{100} C_{a}^{i}\Bigg[ \sum_{j}^{100} C_{b}^{j}U_{ij} \Bigg]$$
2. $$T_{ib} = \sum_{j}^{100} C_{b}^{j}U_{ij}, U'_{ab} =\sum_{i}^{100} C_{a}^{i}T_{ib} $$

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the structure of the computation.  For 1,presumably you start with $j=1$ so there are $100$ terms inside the square brackets, each with one multiply.  Then you add them all together to get a constant.  What happens in the outer sum?  How many terms, how many multiplies per term?